# How to set up Monero GUI wallet + Trezor on Tails

Tags: trezor

I have Tails 4.2.2, Trezor T firmware 2.2.0 and Monero GUI wallet 15.0.2. There is a lot of help on how to get the GUI wallet and Trezor working as well as GUI wallet and Tails. However, there is no user guide on how to get all three working together with a full or remote node.

The questions/problems I have are:

1) Would I need the Trezor bridge for the GUI wallet (I know I need it for updating the trezor firmware, but this is done elsewhere)?

2) Why would the wallet not recognise my Trezor T when setting up a hardware wallet in Tails? I read the problem should have been solved with version 15.0.2.

3) Do I need to change the iptables settings or any other settings?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

1. You shouldn't need the Bridge as that is for browser <=> USB communication.
2. It is [supposed to work out of the box](https://www.reddit.com/r/tails/comments/8vnnui/trezor_when_will_it_work_outofthebox_with_tails/). If it doesn't, you probably need `udev` rules setup so the OS can see the device: https://wiki.trezor.io/Udev_rules -- note, if you want these to persist, you need to specially configure that (or copy them each reboot)
3. Tails sends all traffic over Tor, so I believe (may be wrong) no port config should be needed.  You will probably need to run with `torsocks` however. This might be helpful: https://garlicgambit.wordpress.com/2017/01/15/monero-how-to-connect-wallet-to-tor-onion-service-node/